# Processing and Kinect: Change speed of video according to distance from the sensor

Tags: loops, video, processing, kinect, distance

I'm asking a question for a school project. I am trying to play a video in a loop and change its speed according to the distance from the Kinect 1414. When you are far the video plays at normal speed, which then increases as you get closer.

I tried in different ways but sometimes either the video doesn't loop or it doesn't show, I can only hear the audio. Other solutions don't let me change the speed of the video. Do you know any way to have the distance of a person affect the video?

Thanks.

Comment: No homework solving on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't designed for general "how do I do this" type questions like this. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense.

You need to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take on those pieces one at a time. For example, can you start with a very basic sketch that just displays the distance from the Kinect? Don't worry about the video yet, just display the distance on the screen.

Separately from that, can you create another sketch that just shows a video playing in a loop? Work your way up from there: can you make it so its speed is based on a hard-coded value? How about on a value like `mouseX`?

Get those two basic sketches working perfectly by themselves before you start thinking about combining them. Then if you get stuck on one of those steps, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific question (in a new question post), and we'll go from there. Good luck.